# How to do google maps with own markers, text pop-ups on specific locations with clickabkle links

Tags: google-maps

I have found a very nice Google map (which can be found in the footer on this link (https://www.flowbox.com/) And I would like to learn how to do something similar. I am kind of new to web programming. Could somebody advise me, on where to focus my effort? Is it done by some plugin (I have not found any similar) Or it can be done somehow directly in Google Maps itself (then I cannot explain how they forced to use their own dot markers with customized text pop-ups) Or it is done completely by HTML/CSS programming? Thanks a lot.